# PHP: Get a specific Google Calendar feed using Zend?

Tags: php, api, zend-framework, google-calendar-api, zend-gdata

Disclaimer: I did try searching first, and even found [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535361/getting-zend-gdata-feed-for-a-specific-google-calendar), but it didn't match what I'm asking.

I'm just learning to use the Zend framework to integrate Google Calendars into some software I'm building.  Currently I am able to retrieve a list of my calendars, as well as to print events related to my default calendar ([this](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/1.0/developers_guide_php.html#RetrievingCalendars) and [this](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/1.0/developers_guide_php.html#RetrievingWithoutQuery) helped me).

The problem is: I use about 8 different calendars.  **I want to be able to create, update and delete events on one of my non-default calendars.**  I assumed it was in the Zend of Google documentation, specifically passing a parameter to the getCalendarEventFeed() method, but I cannot find any documentation on it.

In summary: **I'd like to be able to use the Zend framework to create/update/delete events on one of my non-default Google Calendars.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the feed id as you are currently accessing the **default** calendar.

For a query it looks something like this: $query->setUser($id_calendar_feed);

On a url it looks something like this: "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/" . $id_calendar_feed . "/private/"